# Check for Duplicates in Array

Tags: arrays, swift, duplicates

I have a custom struct `Shift`:

```
struct Shift: Identifiable, Encodable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var weekday: String
    var startTime: Date
    var endTime: Date
}
```

I also have a variable that stores an `Array` of `Shift`:

```
@Published var shifts: [Shift] = []
```

Is there any way to check if there are duplicate entries of `startTime` and `endTime` rather than checking for the entire `Shift` object?

EDIT:
Basically what I am trying to do is make sure that there aren't multiple shifts on a particular `weekday` that overlap. For instance, if my first shift on Monday starts at 1 pm and ends at 2 pm, there shouldn't be any other shift on Monday within that timeframe. However, I should be able to add a shift on Tuesday, for example, that starts at 1 pm and ends at 2 pm.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: two ideas: Maintain 2 index arrays sorted by start and end, or use a SQL database for your  storage and have it index those fields.  Inserts/updates to the struct array must also update the 2 index arrays which is expensive, but then lookups are cheap.  Possibly only worth it if you do a lot of queries.

Comment: Depending on what other kinds of look-ups you need to handle, it might be worth breaking this down into a `[StartTime: [EndTime: [Shift]]]`

Comment: @Alexander I'm afraid I may not have been very clear in my question so I've added a little explanation if you'd care to read. Also, could you please elaborate on your response? Thank you :)

Comment: So for Tuesday 1 -2, you need to find not just an existing Tuesday 1 - 2 but also overlaps like  a noon - 2 or 11- 3 shift or 1:15 - 1:45?  Please list all of the possible matches and whether or not there will be no existing overlaps.  That is, is it guaranteed  that the existing array has only only one element that "uses" the 1-2 slot.

Comment: @devOP1 What you should be working with is called DateInterval and check if they intersect with each other.

Comment: To start, I'd suggest you just add an `overlapsWith` method, which checks for intersection between `self` and another `Shift (using `DateInterval` under the hood, as Leo suggested). You can compare each shift with every other shift, to find all possible overlaps. This is a naive solution with `O(n^2)` time complexity, but it should be a decent place to start before you resort to more complex CS to speed things up (if/when necessary)

Answer (score 0):

You could add conformance to the `Comparable` protocol, and implement the == operator yourself (by returning true if the two startDates and the two endDates match.) You could then use `contains(:_)` on your array. That would be slow for large arrays though, since each call to `contains(:_)` will take `O(n)` time, and trying to see if an array of objects contains duplicates would degenerate to `O(n^2)` time.

If you also have your Shift object conform to Hashable (and use the 2 dates to calculate the hash value) you could use a set to test for duplicates. You'd populate your set with your array and then use the set to test new items for membership. (Sets give nearly constant time for checking for membership.)

Comment: If the test is for both start and end matching, and only one record is allowed to use both, then a map would work.  make the key std::string = start + end.  I was assuming duplicates are allowed and you are looking for duplicates of start or end, not just start and end.  Of course this might be an XY question where what's really needed is detecting overlapping times not start == start and/or end == end.

Comment: @DaveS and Duncan C, thank you very much for your responses. I'm afraid I may not have been very clear in my question. I have added a small explanation if you'd care to read :)